# How to retrieve a list from DynamoDB?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Im having a specific error when running a scan expression on a table within my DynamoDB Database. There is one item in my Projects table as of now. This item contains a project description and a **list of Strings** of team mates. When retrieving the information for the project description my code prints out the correct name of the project. However when trying to retrieve the list of team mates from this same item it says that the list is a null object reference. I can not seem to understand why the list being returned is null. Assume all permissions have been set properly within the IAM console, and the database.

Below is the code for my thread which scans the table.

```
  public void run() {
                DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
  //returns a list of items from the table. each item is of Project type
                List<Project> scanResult=mapper.scan(Project.class,scanExpression);
 //for each project within scanResult do the following
                for (Project project: scanResult){
//retrieve the name of the team (this portion of the code logs the project name properly)
                    String team=project.getProjectname();
                    Log.v("team",team.toString());
//The list being returned from this one line below is null??
                    List<String> teammates=project.getTeammates();

                    Log.v("Teammate", teammates.get(0));
                }

            }

        };

        Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
        mythread.start();
```

Below is the code for the Projects Class which serves as a template when scanning the table. This is most likely the area of the issue because the project description string is being returned properly, however the List of teamMates isnt. Perhaps I am not supposed to be using a List, or the List is not defined properly, or the use of Java annotations is not done correctly on this table !!!! However I can not find the issue

```
package com.example.varun.finalproject;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.*;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Varun on 4/10/17.
 */
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "SBUProjects")

public class Project {
private String ProjectName;
private List<String> TeamMates;
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "ProjectName")
    public String getProjectname() {
        return ProjectName;
    }

    public void setProjectname(String projectName) {
        this.ProjectName = projectName;
    }

    public List<String> getTeammates() {
        return TeamMates;
    }

    public void setTeammates(List teammates) {
        this.TeamMates= TeamMates;
    }

    }
```

Lastly here is a photo of my table and the item that contains a String for the project description and a **List of Strings** for my TeamMates. I assumed because the table determined teamMates to be a list I should also create a List when returning teamMates.

http://i67.tinypic.com/2qnm58h.jpg
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set annotation above the getTeammates() method, similar to how you set it for the getProjectname() method.

For example,
`@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "teammates")`